# Microsoft Graph - create shared mailbox folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a shared mailbox using Microsoft Graph, but I can't find this API method. I found API how to create simple mailbox folder:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0

How to create group:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0

but no found how to create shared mailbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SharedMailbox by applying some 'Shared' permitions to the API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

You must also use a variation on the URL (/users/sharedaddress@email.com/EmailFolder).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Can you please explain more? I cannot seem to find the API that creates a shared mailbox.

Comment: I guess it is not possible. The link that's in the answer isn't relevant. Not sure why it was accepted as a valid answer.